# Run Macro Win32com with python, Filename Excel Spaces issue

Tags: python, excel, vba

I had a issue with running a macro from an excel with python/flask.

When the file don't have spaces on his name works okay and run the macro, if the file have spaces in the filename i can't run it.

Here's the code of the py file

```
    app.route('/process_done', methods=['POST'])    
def runmacros():
     run_macro("Main System FIndx.xlsm!Test_macro.Prueba","..\System\Main Test.xlsm") 


 return render_template('main.jade')
```

and the function

```
def run_macro(macroname, filetorun):
        pythoncom.CoInitialize ()
        xlApp = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
        xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filetorun)
        xlSht = xlWb.WorkSheets(1)
        xlApp.visible = True
        xlApp.Application.Run(macroname)
        xlWb.Saved = 0
        xlWb.Save()
        xlWb.Close(SaveChanges=True)
        xlApp.application.Quit()
```

So if the file rename to "MainTest" the macro runs when the button template is pressed, but if I called "Main Test" doesn't work.

Maybe the solution is very easy but I can find it.

Thanks in advance.

pd: the problem is displayed when I try to run the macro, the file did open without problem.

EDIT:

SOLVED

on the xlApp.Application.Run python doesn't need the whole name so i changed Main System FIndx.xlsm!Test_macro.Prueba to "Test_macro.Prueba" and works! :D

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

on the xlApp.Application.Run python doesn't need the whole name so i changed Main System FIndx.xlsm!Test_macro.Prueba to "Test_macro.Prueba" and works! :D